# Destroy all GameObjects but keep spawning new ones - Unity3D C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When my spaceship dies, I move it to a new random position at the top of the screen. When my spaceship dies, I want to destroy all meteoroids but keep spawning new meteoroids.

When I loop and destroy all meteoroids, no new meteoroids are spawned.

I'm trying to replicate the following Scratch game I created in 2015:
[Homesick Cody](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/55951104/)

Some suggestions are to keep count of how many meteoroids and spawn one before deleting the last one. I'm a bit lost on how to do this. And maybe there is a better way.

**Meteoroid.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Meteoroid : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] 
    private GameObject spaceship;

    [SerializeField] 
    private float speed = 1.0f;

    [SerializeField] 
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, spaceship.transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.up = spaceship.transform.position - transform.position;
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        foreach (var meteoroid in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("meteoroid"))
        {
            Destroy(meteoroid);
        }
    }

}
```

**MeteoroidSpawn.cs**

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MeteoroidSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SpawnRoutine());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    [SerializeField] 
    private GameObject meteoroid; //prefab

    [SerializeField]
    private bool spawn = true;

    IEnumerator SpawnRoutine()
    {
        Vector2 spawnPos = Vector2.zero;
        
        while (spawn == true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);

            // Spawn meteoroid
            spawnPos.x = Random.Range(-Screen.width/40, Screen.width/40);
            spawnPos.y = -Screen.height/40;
            meteoroid = Instantiate(meteoroid, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How is set the field `MeteoroidSpawn.meteoroid`?

Comment: Can you provide a little more info? This being my first ever C# program.

Comment: Somewhere in the `MeteoroidSpawn` class, there is a line like `meteoroid = ...`. Can you add this line in the question?

Comment: That's my entire MeteoroidSpawn.cs above, maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: `"The game object has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it."` sounds quite self-explanatory to me ... debug your code with breakpoints and recheck all the references you are dstroying .. at some point you are seemingly trying to do something with an object that already has been destroyed

Comment: where is your code for when you destroy the spaceship / all meteoroids?

Comment: I think I got it `meteoroid = Instantiate(meteoroid, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);`

Comment: I don't get the error message anymore but when I loop and destroy all meteoroids, no more are spawned, code updated in question.

Answer (score 1):

1. It seems like you're trying to destroy meteoroids on just any collision. It would be great if you could also check that the collision of the meteoroid was with an actual spaceship. This might not be necessary just now, but it might backfire if any 2 meteoroids collide with each other, or with other game objects that you might add later.

Assuming your spaceship has a Tag `Player`:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")
        {
            Debug.Log("collision");
            Destroy(gameObject);  // I want to destroy all meteoroids when spaceship dies
        }
    }
```

2. I assume you are destroying meteoroids that leave the game area so that they're not wasting resources.
3. Your meteoroids don't get destroyed all at once because each one holds its own instance of the `Meteoroid` script and each one will separately run their own `OnCollisionEnter2D()`. Thus, if a meteoroid hits the player, it checks only for the collision between itself and the other collider.

If you want to destroy all meteoroids at once, you will have to store them somehow and then on any collision between any Meteoroid, invoke some method that can access all stored meteoroids and destroy them all at once.
Your `MeteoroidSpawn` class seems like a good place to do this for now:

```
public class MeteoroidSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<Meteoroid> meteoroids; // Stores all currently spawned Meteoroids.

    [SerializeField] 
    private GameObject meteoroidPrefab;

    private bool spawn = true;

    private void Start()
    {
        meteoroids = new List<Meteoroid>();  // Create and initialize the list.
        StartCoroutine(SpawnRoutine());
    }

    IEnumerator SpawnRoutine()
    {
        Vector2 spawnPos = Vector2.zero;
        
        while (spawn == true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);

            // Spawn meteoroid
            spawnPos.x = Random.Range(-Screen.width/40, Screen.width/40);
            spawnPos.y = -Screen.height/40;
            var meteor = Instantiate(meteoroidPrefab, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
            
            // Add new meteoroid to the list.
            meteoroids.Add(meteor.GetComponent<Meteoroid>());
        }
    }
}
```

Now that you have a reference to all spawned meteoroids, you can destroy them all in whatever fashion you like, i.e. write a static method in the `MeteoroidSpawn.cs` that will destroy meteoroids and call it from a Meteoroid.cs on a collission (remember that you would also have to **make the `List<Meteoroid>` static**).

Such code could look like this (`MeteoroidSpawn.cs`):

```
public static void DestroyAllMeteoroids()
{
    foreach (var meteoroid in meteoroids)
        Destroy(meteoroid.gameObject);
}
```

and could be called like this (`Meteoroid.cs`):

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")
        {
            Debug.Log("collision");
            MeteoroidSpawn.DestroyAllMeoroids();
        }
    }
```

###### Event approach

Another way is to use events. Unity provides an event system of its own ([UnityEvent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html)) but I personally prefer to use ordinary [C# events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/) for as light work as this:

`Meteoroid.cs`:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Meteoroid : MonoBehaviour
{
    public event EventHandler OnSpaceshipHit;

    [SerializeField] 
    private GameObject spaceship;

    [SerializeField] 
    private float speed = 1.0f;

    [SerializeField] 
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, spaceship.transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.up = spaceship.transform.position - transform.position;
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")
        {
            Debug.Log("collision");
            OnSpaceshipHit?.Invoke(this, null); // Raise event.
        }
    }

}
```

And inside `MeteoroidSpawn.cs`:

```
private List<Meteoroid> meteoroids; // Stores all currently spawned Meteoroids.

private void Start()
{
    meteoroids = new List<Meteoroid>();  // Create and initialize the list.
    StartCoroutine(SpawnRoutine());
}
    
// Rest of the code.

IEnumerator SpawnRoutine()
{
    Vector2 spawnPos = Vector2.zero;
    
    while (spawn == true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);

        // Spawn meteoroid
        spawnPos.x = Random.Range(-Screen.width/40, Screen.width/40);
        spawnPos.y = -Screen.height/40;
        Meteoroid meteor = Instantiate(meteoroidPrefab, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity).GetComponent<Meteoroid>();
        meteor.OnSpaceshipHit += DestroyAllMeteoroids; // Subscribe to the event.
            
        // Add new meteoroid to the list.
        meteoroids.Add(meteor);
    }
}

private void DestroyAllMeteoroids(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var meteoroid in meteoroids)
        Destroy(meteoroid.gameObject);
}
```

With this setup, you subscribe to the `OnSpaceshipHit` event of every new meteoroid. Now every meteoroid has a way to let the Spawner know that it had hit the player. If that happens, an event is raised and the `DestroyAllMeteoroids()` method is called, destroying all meteoroids in the process. No static methods or variables needed. There is also no need to unsubscribe from the event, since you're destroying the game object the same frame the collision happens.

Let me know if you need any further explanation of the code.

Comment: The meteoroids do not do anything if they collide with each other. The meteoroids follow the spaceship, so they do not leave the game area. Destroying all the meteoroids is taken care of. But I want them to keep spawning. The problem is they stop spawning when they're all destroyed.

Comment: To be fair the question was badly asked .. the code wasn't the actually used one which has a simple issue of overwriting the original prefab field with the latest instance. However, most of this answer is slightly off-topic / not on scope for the question. Introducing the tags is a good idea generally but is only adding a condition when to destroy single objects which is not really relevant here. Also the event based code is a good idea generally but the questions scope is actually not really how/when exactly the `DestroyAllMeteoroids` is called but rather what it does ;)

Comment: The latter I think I had actually already covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73551948/7111561) anyway ;) The collision now assumes that your spaceship dies with the first meteoroid which might o might not be true (e.g. having lives or certain amount of damage points)

Comment: @derHugo Yes, I just noticed that the code in the question has been changed. I may have gone a little bit out of scope of the question as well, that's true, but perhaps OP can come back to it later and make more use of it then; it is another way of solving one of their issues after all!

Comment: @Harley They should still keep spawning. I noticed you are now using the tag "meteoroid". Make sure that the game object that holds the ```MeteoroidSpawn``` script does NOT have this tag set on it! Otherwise it will also get destroyed and no meteors will spawn.

Comment: @crsmn If I remove the tag I get "The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it"

Comment: @Harley Are you still using this snippet?
```meteoroid = Instantiate(meteoroid, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);``` 
You should keep the prefab object separate from the spawned object.  
```GameObject newMeteor = Instantiate(meteoroidPrefab, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);```

Comment: @crsmn With or without the `meteoroid = ` seems to make no difference, yes I've still got it

Comment: @Harley When you double click on the error in Unity, to which line does it point you to in code?

Comment: @crsmn right now there are no errors appearing but the spawning doesn't restart. I read that about keeping the prefab separate earlier today, just haven't got it to work yet

Comment: In `DestroyAllMeteoroids` you should also add `meteoroids.Clear();` in the end ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

After you edited your question with apprently the acual code it is clear that this line

```
meteoroid = Instantiate(meteoroid, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
```

causes the issue that the new spawned `meteoroid` is a clone of the previous one.

So of course as soon as you destroy the last instantiated instance `meteoroid` becomes an invalid object which can not be used as a prefab for `Instantiate` anymore.

I see no reason why you would need to update the field at all

=>

```
Instantiate(meteoroid, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
```

---

*original before edit of the question*

Not an answer to where your error comes from but I would simply keep track of all instances e.g. by having them under a specific parent object:

```
Instantiate(meteoroid, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity, transform);
```

then you can simply have a method like

```
public void DestroAllCurrenMeteroids()
{
    foreach(Transform child in transform)
    {
        Destroy(child.gameObject);
    }
}
```

---

As a more fancy alternative you can do it within the type itself in a collection like e.g.

```
public class Meteoroid : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static readonly HashSet<Meteoroid> instances = new ();

    ...

    private void Awake()
    {
        instances.Add(this);
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        instances.Remove(this);
    }

    public static void DestroyAllInstances()
    {
        foreach(var instance in instances)
        {
            Destroy(instance.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

so from everywhere you can simply call

```
Meteoroid.DestroyAllInstances();
```

Comment: Is that better than using tags? I'm brand new to this.

Comment: It is something completely different then the answer with the tags. The tags only add an additional condition to when a meteoroid is destroyed which is actually out of scope of your question ... The "event approach" part focuses on ho exactly the destroyallmeteorois method is called .. which actually is also out of scope for your question ;)    Define "better" ... the other answer also simply uses a collection o keep track of instantiated objects .. so basically it is a clone of what I do ;)

Comment: I tried your approach but I still get the problem of no more meteoroids being spawned after `DestroyAllInstances()`. I'm kinda back to square one.

Comment: You are correct `meteoroid = ` makes no difference.

Comment: after you call it ... does `MeteoroidSpawn` still exist in your scene? sounds to me like you are destroying or disabling it somewhere

Comment: it's still there

Comment: @Harley is there anything else you do in the reset of the spaceship that might have any side effects? E.g. playing with the `Time.timeScale` (0 would prevent the ` yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);` from ever finishin) or disabling the `MeteoroidSpawn` component ... besides these I don't see a reason why it should not spawn if this component still exists and is active and enabled and you get no errors ...